# Boundary points of the set D={(x,y): |y |>= x}

Tags: calculus, boundary-value-problem

What are the boundary points of the set in xy-plane
$$ D=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2<1, |y| \geqslant x\} $$

Should it be $bdry(D)=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1, |y|=x\}$ or $bdry(D)=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1, |y|\geqslant x\}$ ? That is the absolut value that I am not sure about.

Comment: Both options that you present are incorrect. I would recommend that you draw a sketch of the set $D$, and then make a guess as to the boundary based on that picture.

Comment: I did draw a sketch of the set, but I don't really get the problem. Could you explain a little bit more? Did you suggest that $ x^2 + y^2 = 1 $ is not a boundary?

Comment: @Angelina the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is **part** of the boundary, but there is a piece that you are missing.

Comment: @Angelina Does your sketch look [something like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3C+1+and+%7Cy%7C+%3E%3D+x%2C+x+%3D+-2...+2%2C+y%3D-2...+2)?